# Get Column Headers where value exists, Excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, formula, heading

I am trying to create a column that concatenates the headings from other columns, based on the location of a value within the range of data under the headings using an excel formula. My table looks like this:

```
2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017
-------------------------
1234   4567   6547   1234
2583   3698   4567   3214
9874   1234   6664   5896
```

Now, this table has an extensive list of rows with values.

I want to create a cell that a user can type a number in and it will return the row heading(s) in the cell adjacent to it. if the number occurs in more than one column, than concatenate the headings using a comma separator. i.e.

```
Enter Number:    Years Occurred 
    1234         2014,2015,2017
```

Rules: Each column has a list of unique numbers. No number occurs in a column more than once.

The best example I can find is here, where the formula returns the heading for the max value of the range of data:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2547-excel-find-highest-value-in-a-row-and-return-column-title.html

Thanks

Comment: What version of excel?

Comment: Excel 2010. I see the note that Scott Craner made in his response below for differing versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN as an Array Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A1:D1,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A2:D4)/(A2:D4=F2),ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,COUNTIF(A2:D4,F2))))*{1,1})))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Note: TEXTJOIN is available with Office 365 Excel and not earlier versions.

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then you will need some helper columns.

In the first Helper cell put:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($F$4,A:A,0)),"," & A1,"")
```

Then copy over the same number of columns as your data.

Then use this to concatenate:

```
=MID(H4&I4&J4&K4,2,999)
```

Adding cells for more columns.

[image]

Comment: Hey @Scott Craner. thanks for the response. I don't have 365. I'm working in Excel 2010 so I'm using your second method. I'm definitely getting something wrong here. When you say "In the first put", do you mean the first cell (A1) or do you mean the first helper column (F4)? I've played around a coupe times and I'm getting errors. When copying over the number of columns as my data, is that why you are placing the years in cells H4, I4 and K4? If so, why is 2016 missing? Thanks!

Comment: The first formula went in H4 and copy/dragged across. Then the second went in G4.